# Unable to get time taken in tomcat access logs for wso2am 3.1.0

Tags: tomcat, wso2, wso2-api-manager, access-log

We have followed up the steps in below documentation to collect suitable information about each requests time taken handled by the api manager, both at the tomcat access log and the API Gateway log:

> https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/monitoring-http-access-logs/

However ti appears as if the %T (or the %D) format specifier placed in the access-log.properties is being ignored (or is not being recognized), given that however we use it, we either get a dash ("-") for every log entry, or in some cases information regarding the mime tipe of the resource being served, instead of the expected time taken value.

Has anywone faced a similar issue before?
Is there a way to fix it, or are there any workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this up.

The Passthrough Access Logs doesn't provide the round-trip time logging at the moment in API Manager 3.1.0, and the Documentation that you have referred to needs to be updated. As per the current implementation [git](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/v2.1.7-wso2v147/modules/transports/core/nhttp/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/http/access/Access.java#L826-L827), the `%T` provides the `Content-Type` of the request as you have observed in your logs.

I have raised a [Git issue](https://github.com/wso2/docs-apim/issues/4284) to update the docs accordingly.